Can you Parallelize specific code chunks in R?
Is it possible to parallelize all the operations with in separate code chunks. For example, I have 3 code chunks that query separate tables in a database. I then perform some data cleaning. Is it possible to have each code chunk be broken into its own process to be ran on a core at the same time as other code chunks? Essentially have process 1+2+3 going at the same time on separate cores instead of sequentially.
Process 1
q_flighthistory <- "SELECT *
                    FROM CT_FLIGHT_HISTORY;" # WHERE FLIGHT_DATE BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-07-02';"

dbGetQuery(q_flighthistory, "view_flighthistory")


# Unique flight history for that date
clean_flighthistory <- view_flighthistory %>%
  filter(SEGMENT_STATUS == "A") %>% 
  select(c(2:10), (12:13), (55:59),EQUIPMENT) %>% 
  #filter(!duplicated(UNIQUE_ID)) %>% 
  rename(SCHED_DEPARTURE_TIME = SCHED_DEPARTURE_TIME_RAW)%>% 
  mutate(updated_dt = paste(UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_TIME, sep= " ")) %>% 
  group_by(FLIGHT_NO, FLIGHT_DATE, DEPARTING_CITY, ARRIVAL_CITY, SCHED_DEPARTURE_TIME) %>% 
  filter(updated_dt == max(updated_dt)) %>% 
  mutate(temp_id = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(temp_id)) %>% 
  select(!c(12:16)) %>% 
  select(!c(5:7)) %>% 
  select(!c(10:11))

rm(view_flighthistory)
gc()


Process 2
q_flightleg <- "SELECT *
                FROM CT_FLIGHT_LEG;" # WHERE PAIRING_DATE BETWEEN '2024-06-28' AND '2024-07-02';"

dbGetQuery(q_flightleg, "view_flightleg")


flight_leg_join <-  view_flightleg %>% 
  mutate(updated_dt = paste(UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_TIME, sep= " "),
         shed_dept_hour = hour(SCHED_DEPARTURE_TIME),
         DEADHEAD = if_else(is.na(DEADHEAD), "C", DEADHEAD)) %>%
  relocate(updated_dt, .after=PAIRING_NO) %>%
  group_by(PAIRING_POSITION,
           DEPARTING_CITY,
           ARRIVAL_CITY,
           SCHED_DEPARTURE_DATE,
           shed_dept_hour,
           PAIRING_NO,
           PAIRING_DATE) %>% 
  filter(DEADHEAD == "C",
         updated_dt == max(updated_dt)) %>% 
  mutate(temp_id = cur_group_id(), .after = CREW_INDICATOR) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(temp_id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(PAIRING_NO, PAIRING_DATE, FLIGHT_NO, SCHED_DEPARTURE_DATE, SCHED_ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTING_CITY, ARRIVAL_CITY,
        PAIRING_POSITION)

rm(view_flightleg)
gc()


Process 3
# MasterPairing Query
q_masterpairing <- "SELECT *
                    FROM CT_MASTER_PAIRING;" # WHERE PAIRING_DATE BETWEEN '2024-06-28' AND '2024-07-02';"
dbGetQuery(q_masterpairing, "view_masterpairing")


join_masterpairing <- view_masterpairing %>% 
    mutate(updated_dt = paste(UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_TIME, sep = " ")) %>% 
    relocate(updated_dt, .after=PAIRING_NO) %>%
    group_by(PAIRING_DATE, CREW_ID) %>% 
    filter(updated_dt == max(updated_dt),
           PAIRING_STATUS == "A") %>% 
  select(PAIRING_POSITION, CREW_ID, PAIRING_NO, PAIRING_DATE, CREW_INDICATOR, updated_dt) %>% 
  ungroup()
  
rm(view_masterpairing)
gc()


You can use the future package to run R code asynchronously.

ya I started reading up on that package but uncertain how to implement it fully across my example.

If better performance is the goal, you might try duckplyr or dtplyr, which are wrappers that adapt dplyr code to use faster backends from duckdb and data.table. I expect those would enable orders of magnitude more performance improvement than parallelization. dplyr is pretty fast for many things, but in my experience it is much slower than alternatives when you have many (e.g. >10k, say) groups in your data.

You can use callr::r_bg() to start a new R process in the background.  You can run several simultaneously and then periodically check the status. callr can also keep persistent R sessions alive.

Yes. However for anything really long usually the bottleneck is within-chunk and that's where you'd want to process in parallel.
